# Cauchy schwarz on the trace of product of two symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A, B$ be two symmetric matrices. The problem is to upper and lower bound the term $\text{Tr}(AB)$ in terms of $\text{Tr}(A)$ and $\text{Tr}(B).$

Comment: If $A = B = \operatorname{diag} (1,-1)$ then the traces are zero, but the trace of $AB$ is 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, you need Cauchy-Schwarz. The form $[A,B]=\text{Tr}(AB^*) $ is an inner product. So $$|\text{Tr} (AB)|\leq\text{Tr}(A^*A)^{1/2}\text{Tr}(B^*B)^{1/2}. $$
This works for any $A,B $, not necessarily symmetric (or selfadjoint if you talk complex).

If instead you want bounds in terms of the traces of $A $ and $B $, then no such bounds exist. Copper Hat's example and variations of it can show it clearly.